# Can someone explain why these specific changes to my array fix my errors?

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

I'm starting to teach myself Java with an online tutorial and am having difficulty understanding what I am supposed to be doing in this situation:

TASK: "Change the values in numbers so it will not raise an error."

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3};
        int length = numbers[3];
        char[] chars = new char[length];
        chars[numbers.length + 4] = 'y';
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```

I checked the solution but still don't understand what the error is and how this fixes it:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3};
        int length = numbers[2];
        char[] chars = new char[length];
        chars[numbers.length - 1] = 'y';
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I now understand the changing of 3 to 2 but why change the +4 to -1?

Comment: Check this picture: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/java/objects-tenElementArray.gif

Comment: Most things in programming (arrays including) are indexed from 0. So which element would `[3]` should return?

Comment: Problem is here: int length = numbers[3], you only have the index set to 3 indices, but arrays start with a 0 length

Comment: Thanks, I know I'm asking questions that may seem silly to you, but I did just start 10 minutes ago :) Why change the +4 to -1?

Comment: `chars[numbers.length - 1]` will access the last element of the `chars` array. `chars[numbers.length + 4]` will give you an index out of bounds exception

Comment: @FrustratedTechNewb Since you just started 10 minutes ago, I will suggest that you spend way more time searching for the answer online/trying to understand it before asking a question about it. A good rule of thumb for this site is to spend at least a couple days looking for the answer. Chances are your question is answered in another, similar question on the site already :-) Especially if you are asking basic questions (by your own admittance)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's go this through line by line.

```
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3};
```

This creates an array with 3 elements. The first being 1, the second 2 and the third 3.

```
int length = numbers[3];
```

The length of said array is 3 is we learned. Since the third's element's value is 3 too, you use this value. But the index of an array starts with 0, so `numbers[3]` (3 is the index) causes an error. `numbers[0]` is 1, `numbers[1]` is 3, `numbers[2]` is 3. `numbers[3]` is wrong.

```
char[] chars = new char[length];
```

This creates a new array, this time not of numbers, but of characters. Such as `'a'`, `'b'` or `'y'`. The length of the array is 3.

```
chars[numbers.length + 4] = 'y';
```

`numbers.length` is 3. Adding 4 to this is 7. As you learned, an index of 7 refers to the eighths element of an array. Since `chars` is only 3 elements long, this would cause an error. So we have to change the four into something that, when added to 3, is smaller than 3 but greater or equal to 0. So you could change it to -1, -2 or -3.

```
System.out.println("Done!");
```

This only outputs "Done!" to the console, no magic here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer would be to change "the values in 'numbers'"

```
    int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 9};
```

Or rather adding any number greater than or equal to 9 would be ok, actually.

This means 'length' will be 9, the 'chars' array will be of length 9, and indexing of element [4(*) + 4] will not yield an ArrayOutOfBoundsException

(*) The 4 is the length of 'numbers' array.

Like this:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 9};
    int length = numbers[3];
    char[] chars = new char[length];
    chars[numbers.length + 4] = 'y';
    System.out.println("Done!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This has been answered and my own answer is probably not the best but I just commented out chars[numbers.length + 4] = 'y';.
I made it look like this **//**chars[numbers.length + 4] = 'y';

Comment: OP is asking for an explanation on why the changes fix the error. Your suggestion to comment out the line that raises the error will certainly avoid the error, but will not append the array with the 'y'... so this is actually far less helpful than you think. One of the things that is important when answering a question is to have a good understanding of what OP was trying to do.